# How to delete a property from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I want to delete a test property from Google Analytics, but there is no delete option on the property page. Does anyone know how to delete a property from Google Analytics?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 376, accepted):

**UPDATE/EDIT – December 5, 2014** : Converted this to community wiki… feel invited to edit and update.

---

**UPDATE/EDIT – AUGUST 1, 2014**

Google has done it again… they changed the design. But they also made things a bit simpler and more logic. Go to `Administration → Property Settings` and look for the `Delete Property` link at the right-bottom of the page. Click that link to delete the property.

Here’s a schreenshot of the current (2014-08-01) interface, pointing to the link you’re looking for…

> [image: screenshot]

Note that the RGB noise is not part of the Google design. I added that to protect personal information. ;)

---

## Stop reading here…

What follows was my original answer, which has been rendered obsolete by Google’s design update on 2014-08-01. For potential reference purposes, I’ve decided to not yet remove that outdated info…

---

Google decided to move that feature into the `View Settings`. To find it, go to the "View Settings" in your Admin area…

> [image: Step 1]

Then click the link to delete it…

> [image: Step 2]

Comment: THANK YOU! That Admin UI is such a disaster.

Comment: It seems Google's UI choices outside of their main search engine are so unintuitive it's actually painful.

Comment: For me it's currently showing up in the top-right section of the page, as a button, still reading "Delete property".

Comment: @Gelldur As I’m low on time to update it again, I converted the answer to a community wiki… please feel invited to edit and update the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You have to select the Property first and then under `Profile` click on **Profile Settings**. At the bottom of that page there is a **"delete this profile"** link:

> [image: screenshot]

This was really annoying, and I spent a good chuck of time trying to find this horribly hidden feature.

Comment: @yushulx This answer is obsolete, since Google moved the feature. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18815094/2432317).

Comment: Well not "Exactly" I'm afraid, I agree the buttons are still in the same place but think about those who will search for "Profile" and "Profile settings" instead of "View" and "View settings". That's a very small difference but as you said, the feature is already hidden enough.

Answer (score 6):

it can be done, click on admin then under the "all website data" tab, there will be "view settings". Under that - at the bottom - there will be "delete this view". That does the trick.

Answer (score 5):

It is now possible to delete a property from the Admin -> Property Settings page.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to delete the property. Once you deleted last view, the property will be deleted for you  automatically.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @GirishNair how does this not answer the question? Question: How to delete? Answer: You can't, by design.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add couple updates:

1. You need to have admin credentials to be able to remove the property
2. Navigate to Admin->Property Settings, and then delete the selected property by clicking the **Move to Trash Can** button on the right[image]

Answer (score 4):

Google changed the UI of Analytics again, so now it looks slightly different:

Admin >> Select Property >> Property Settings >> Move to Trash Can

[image]

You now have also the possibility to move the Property to a new account instead of deleting it.

If you move the Property to the trash can ypou can restore the property within 35 days and you see the property in the Admin dropdown Property-column.
You find the "Trash Can" in the "Account-Column". Here you can restore "deleted" Property and Views.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Google changed it a little bit now you will get the option of Trash Can. Go to Google Analytics website admin choose your website in Account tab you will see Account Sttings click it than just click to Move To Trash Can. Another page will just confirm and after confirm your entry will be deleted.

Actually it is not deleted it is just invisible from main page. You can restore it within 35 day if you do than you will get your account back else it will be deleted permanently.

You can read the article here : [Remove Account from Google Analytics](http://www.vivekmoyal.in/how-to-remove-website-from-google-analytics/)