# How to delete a Container from Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to delete a Container in my Google Tag Manager Account. But in the settings, there is no delete options. Does anyone know how to delete a container from Google Tag Manager?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to coding at all. Please post to Webmasters perhaps.

Comment: I also wanted to add it there at first, but then I saw this question on stackoverflow, that is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692636/how-to-delete-a-property-from-google-analytics It seems, that this helped a lot of users.

Comment: this question should be asked here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It´s possible to delete Tag Manager Containers.

Klick on "Admin" and choose the Container you want to delete in the second column.

[image]

Now Klick on "Container Settings". In the right corner you can find the "DELETE"-Button.

[image]

The Container you deleted is now in the Trash Can. You can find the Trash Can on the "Account overview" page. You have now 30 days time to restore this Container. After this timeframe the Container is "realy" deleted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @DanielS. Now the delete option moved to three dots on the top right corner of the card.

Comment: I was looking for the button for hours! (well, several minutes).