# How do I prevent images from being my top visited content?

Tags: image, google-analytics

I recently noticed that some of the images on my website are the pages with the most visits according to Google Analytics. The pages could be accessed by clicking them. The result was the pages being opened in a separate tab. I now deactivated this so now one has to right-click and say "open image in new tab" to get the same results as before. Still I'd like to know how this happens? I don't find the images anywhere on top ranked image searches. Also I would like to use this traffic for "real" purposes, instead of linking to images.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's what I tought as well first of all. But after a short research I found questions like the following on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692636/how-to-delete-a-property-from-google-analytics

Comment: This would be better for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com It's not programming related, but is website related. Most likely Google has crawled the images & people are using Google's Images search to view the images. Robots.txt could be used to stop the bots from crawling the site.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will ask questions like that on webmasters.stackexchange.com from now on. But thanks for your answer anyway. I am aware of robots.txt but what I actually meant is how can I redirect users that are visiting this image to the page where this image is instead -or at least do the index page? I just did a short recherche and found out that other websites have the same problem. The images on the index page http://filament-test.com/ can be found with the image search. But there's no redirect when accessing them. Is there any workaround for that?